# Update excel sheet after Adding, deleting, updating row of datagridview

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I imported an excel sheet into a datagridview.
[image: DGV]

After that i was trying to (insert/ delete/ update) a record in excel sheet without using button event. I am trying to do that in the events of datagridview.
So i tried to use some events like `Rowsadded`, `Rowsremoved` and `CellEndEdit`.

**For Example:**
To add a new record in the excel sheet i used this code:

```
         public void InsertnewRaw(string WorkBookPath, string qry) {
             
             string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="      
              + WorkBookPath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
             using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr))
             {
                 con.Open();
                 System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand =     
                 new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();

                 myCommand.Connection = con;
                 myCommand.CommandText = qry;
                 myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 con.Close();
             }
     }
```

and in the `Rowsadded` event of datagridview i used this code:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        string qry = string.Format("Insert into [Sheet1$] ([id],[Student name])       
        values('" + dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex].Value + "','" + 
        dataGridView1[1, e.RowIndex].Value + "')");

        //Calling the insertnewraw function 
        InsertnewRaw(FirstYearData[1],qry);
    }
```

But this exception is fired:

[image: Exception]

Any advice to do that correctly ?
**"Adding,deleting,updating" excel sheet into datagridview event**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure you want to use the grids “RowAdded” event for this. This event will fire as soon as the row is added. If the user types a single character into the new row, the new rows event will fire at that time. This means that if you use this event to write back to the Excel file, you will most likely miss some of the data. Example, the user types a character into a cell in the new row, the new rows event will fire and the Excel file will update. If the user then clicks into another cell in the same row, the new row event will not fire and the excel file will not be updated.

Comment: In addition, if you wire up the “RowsAdded” event BEFORE you add a `DataSource` you will get the error “index out of range” as you indicate. This error is going to come from `dataGridView1[1, e.RowIndex].Value`… when the data source is set and the first row is set, it will do so one column at a time, therefore, when the data source is set the first time the line will fail because there is NOT a column one (1), there is only column zero (0). If you wire up the “RowsAdded” event AFTER you set the data source or turn it off before you set the data source, it should work as expected.

Comment: Lastly, as I mentioned earlier, the rows added event isn’t going to give you what you want because it will fire BEFORE the user has had time to add the data. I am guessing that using a “Save” button would be an easier approach as opposed to automatically writing back to the Excel file EVERY TIME a cell value changes. If you must have the Excel file updated with any changes made to the grid… I am guessing the “CellValueChanged” would be a better approach as it will not fire until the user has actually made the data change.

Comment: Ok, i understand your answer but if i use     'CellValueChanged'  how can i write my Query ?

Comment: Thanks i use CellValueChanged event and it works well !

Comment: Glad you got it working. Is there some reason you do not want to use a “Save” button?

Comment: I have 4 datagridviews and i do not want to add a lot of buttons So i want to insert a new row , update and delete a row. I think it will be good if i use datagridview directly. What is your opinion ?

Comment: I guess this would depend on how big the data is. I would think that if the grid has an underlying data source such as a `DataTable`, I would use that `DataTable` to simply update/overwrite the database and not really be concerned about “what” “kind” of operation was done (update, new row, deleted). Overwriting the original database will accomplish an update, new row or deleted row using a single method. Again, just a thought.

Comment: it is a good idea , Thanks bro for your help